# I have a need to perform two actions on a simple input form? I have read and tried all previous answers on this subject with no success

Tags: html, forms, action

The following code shows how I am trying to first write info to .txt file and then have the custom search performed. If I remark out the action in Button2, Button1 works fine and writes text to .txt. When I open Button2 to do search, it appears that the .php in Button1 is ignored and Button2 presents custom search, however, there is write to .txt file. I have tried everything I can find, including all in one .php file, but the second action seems to take control and won't allow the first action to run.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>If NOT found to right ENTER Your</title>
    <script language="Javascript">
    <!--
    function OnButton1()
    {
        // Action used to write to .txt file only
        document.Form1.action = "open-close.php";
    }
    function OnButton2()
    {
        // Action performs custom google search
        document.Form1.action = "http://www.google.com";
    }

    -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h3><span style="color: #00ff00;">If NOT found to right ENTER Your Topic Here!        </span></h3>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://www.google.com/cse/api/branding.css);
    </style>
    <div class="cse-branding-right" style="background-color:#999999;color:#000000">
      <div class="cse-branding-form">
        <form id="cse-search-box" target="_blank" name="Form1">
          <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
            <input type="text" name="q" size="55" />
            <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" Onclick="OnButton1(); OnButton2();"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="cse-branding-logo">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/images/poweredby_transparent/poweredby_999999.gif" alt="Google"                 />
      </div>
      <div class="cse-branding-text">
        Your Custom Search
      </div>
    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call OnButton1() on button click and from within the function onButton1() call onButton2():

```
<input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" Onclick="OnButton1();"/>



 function OnButton1()
    {
        // Action used to write to .txt file only
        document.Form1.action = "open-close.php";
    OnButton2();

    }
```

Comment: Nice try, still runs OnButton2 and ignores the .php write file before it? Would it make any difference if I use OnSubmit instead of onclick?